# What tools are needed to make a minimalist graphics?

Tags: software-recommendation, minimalistic

Consider the cover picture on this website - [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/)

It looks so good, despite not having much detail and not even many colors. What tools/software might be used to create such graphics?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome on GD, theironhide, you can use a vector tool like [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org) for such a graphic (in the site the background is a compressed SVG, you can save it and made some experiments). But creating a minimalist image needs also a lot of synthesis.

Comment: Or my personal facovorite.... Notepad :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any vector-based program will do. The *de facto* industry leader is [Adobe Illustrator](http://www.adobe.com/products/illustrator.html), but there's plenty of competition in programs like [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) and [Sketch](https://www.sketchapp.com/).

With some effort, you could even make this in a good raster graphics editor like Photoshop or GIMP, but that's not the recommended way.

Answer (score 0):

Vector software is what would be recommended for that style of graphics (colloquially called flat). If you don't want to get a CC subscription just for Illustrator there are a lot of great options, including the newly launched [Affinity Designer](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/affinity-designer/id824171161?mt=12).

That style of graphic is also available to buy on sites like Creative Market or Graphic River, if you just need one to use on your site and aren't out to learn how to become an illustrator.